# Google Finance style time series chart

Tags: gwt, charts, google-visualization, gxt, fusioncharts

I need to plot time stamped sensor data on a chart. There would be 3000 to 15000 data points in a day and I am looking for an interactive chart that is easy to navigate. Google Finance chart widget is perfect for my requirement. It seems to intelligently load data as one scrolls and zooms. 
See: http://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AXOM

I have seen the same widget being used by causes.com which makes me think that it is not a Google proprietary component.
http://www.causes.com/causes/579073-india-against-corruption/impact

Does anyone know where can I find this component or an alternative?

Just FYI: I am using Ext GWT and a Java back end.

Edit: On further search found it on Google Chart Tools. Its use seems to be dependent on Google's infrastructure. I don't want such dependencies in my app and so I guess I will have to settle for an alternative.

Comment: See **Highcharts** or **amCharts**

Answer (score 2):

Use the [**Annotated TimeLine chart**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline) provided in the **Google Visualization API**.
It gives you the same chart that you see in the link http://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AXOM

I have been working on an Ext-Gwt app that requires a chart with somewhat the same specs that you mentioned.
The google api Chart integrates well into my App, and is not that difficult to code. I am pretty satisfied with it and would recommend you to try it out.

It though does need Google Inra to draw the Charts though. So if you can decide on a tradeoff, it would be a great option for you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://dygraphs.com/tests/range-selector.html

[image: zoomable time series with dygraphs]

dygraphs is an open-source self-contained JavaScript library for charting time series, with no dependencies. It automatically scales the graph to match your data, translates times into the correct time zone, can plot CSV files from arbitrary remote URLs etc.